# How to amend my C# code to call in or store my 32bit dll file so I can run it on excel 64bit using COM Wrapper method

Tags: c#, .net

I have never used c# and done COM wrapper method so please bear with me. I'm trying to use the COM wrapper method so I can access my 32bit dll files to run a macro on a 64bit excel.

Here is my code where I was able to create my server for the dll. I don't know what I need to do next to connect my 32bit dll file or store it in that server I suppose.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FileUtils
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("56075aeb-2f20-41d7-b9c5-e41bfd32c8b1")]

    public interface IFileUtils
    {
        string GetFileName(string path);

    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("6d0cadce-a2f1-45fd-964d-fc0219d18c7e")]
    [ProgId("Lib.FileUtils")]

    public class FileUtils : IFileUtils
    {

        public string GetFileName(String path) => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);


    }


}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/registering-the-dll-server-for-surrogate-activation

Comment: is there a more straightforward answer to this?